# Is there anyway to get Charts and reports in .NET Core 3.1 Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, charts, report, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I'm doing restaurant management system C# project in .netcore 3.1 windows application. I need to get reports and charts from the system. But I couldn't find any chart or report controls. When I try to add NuGet packages it is showing errors. Is there any ways to get reports and create charts?
Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, I reproduced your problem.

Microsoft [Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.8) Control can only be used for .NET Framework project. Please refer to the [bottom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to).

Also, based on my test, `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms` doesn't support .NET Core project.

[image]

Therefore, I recommend that you could Request a feature about .NET winform in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=61&entry=suggestion).